# ¿Cómo puedo comparar el length de dos o mas strings dentro de un array?

Tags: javascript

Necesito comparar en un array de string cual tiene el mayor length.

Código Ejemplo:

```js
let arrayTest = ['Arturo', 'Gabriela', 'Herminio', 'Leticia'];
arrayTest.forEach( (item, index, array) => {
    console.log(item, index, array);
})
```

Con item.length puedo obtener el tamaño de cada string en el array, pero ¿cómo puedo compara uno con otro

Answer (score 6):

Solo por no quedarme con la duda acerca de rendimiento entre métodos de arreglos y ciclos experimenté con esto:

```js
let arrayTest = ['Arturo', 'Gabriela', 'Herminio', 'Leticia'];

let maxCadena = arrayTest.reduce((a, b) => (b.length > a.length) ? b : a);
console.log(maxCadena);
```

Con los pocos datos con que se está trabajando se obtienen resultados equiparables al `for` con base en números. [Ejemplo aquí](https://jsben.ch/Id4Yq)

**Nota:** Es probable que los resultados cambien si el conjunto de datos es muy grande.

Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce

`array.reduce()` puede recibir hasta 4 argumentos, en este caso solo se usan 2, el primero que es la variable a retornar (acumulador) que generalmente se usa para sumas y el segundo es el elemento actual en el "ciclo".

Simplemente se analiza si el elemento actual tiene mayor longitud que el "acumulador" para actualizar lo que se va a retornar.

Comment: Con reduce quedan muy parejas las soluciones.. dejan muy para atras al sort... bien visto la utilizacion de reduce... +1

Comment: También tienes mi +1, es lo que hubiera intentado yo. Igualmente te invito a leer [¿Estamos utilizando demasiado poco el cierre por duplicado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4757/estamos-utilizando-demasiado-poco-el-cierre-por-duplicado-no-usamos-demasiado). La pregunta es duplicada.

Comment: Siguiendo con el tema del rendimiento, poner un  array.length en el for hace que lo calcule en cada iteracion, puede haber una diferencia interesante, dejo esto por aquí https://jsben.ch/cAmUe

Comment: @AngelReynaTorrejon, es igual al ejemplo que dejé en la respuesta y en algunas ocasiones gana el for, en otras, gana reduce. Por eso mencioné que el rendimiento es muy similar.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes usar la funcion sort de javascript para ordenar los strings por longitud y luego te quedas con el primero. Le puedes pasar opcionalmente como segundo parametro una funcion anonima que contiene la logica de comparacion.

Dentro de la funcion anonima, comparamos dos valores a y b que representan elementos del array, usamos el atributo length del string como medio de comparacion. Poner **b - a** significa que queremos ordenar el array descendentemente. **a - b** hubiese sido ascendentemente.

De esta forma conseguimos que el string mas largo sea el primer elemento. Por ultimo cojemos ese primer elemento.

```js
let arrayTest = ['Arturo', 'Gabriela', 'Herminio', 'Leticia'];

let cadenaMasLarga = arrayTest .sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0];

console.log(cadenaMasLarga);
```

La documentación explica en detalle como funciona la lógica de comparacion:

> Si se provee compareFunction, los elementos del array son ordenados de
> acuerdo al valor que retorna dicha función de comparación. Siendo a y
> b dos elementos comparados, entonces:
>
> - Si compareFunction(a, b) es menor que 0, se sitúa a en un indice menor
>   que b. Es decir, a viene primero.
> - Si compareFunction(a, b) retorna 0,
>   se deja a y b sin cambios entre ellos, pero ordenados con respecto a
>   todos los elementos diferentes. Nota: el estandar ECMAscript no
>   garantiza este comportamiento, por esto no todos los navegadores
>   (p.ej.  Mozilla en versiones que datan hasta el 2003) respetan esto.
> - Si compareFunction(a, b) es mayor que 0, se sitúa b en un indice menor
>   que a. compareFunction(a, b) siempre debe retornar el mismo valor dado
>   un par especifico de elementos a y b como sus argumentos. Si se
>   retornan resultados inconsistentes entonces el orden de ordenamiento
>   es indefinido.

[Enlace de la documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

Comment: También tienes mi +1. Igualmente te invito a leer [¿Estamos utilizando demasiado poco el cierre por duplicado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4757/estamos-utilizando-demasiado-poco-el-cierre-por-duplicado-no-usamos-demasiado). La pregunta es duplicada.

Answer (score 5):

**Nota previa: hicimos testeos, y para pocos datos, la solucion con sort o esta aportada tardan lo mismo. Para casos con mas datos, la diferencia de tiempo es sustancial en favor de esta. ver [aca](https://jsben.ch/I99yY)**

Aunque ordenar es una buena idea, se puede hacer de una forma mucho mas simple sin depender de que esperemos por el orden, simplemente comparando cada elemento con el mayor encontrado hasta ahora, que para empezar podemos poner como vacio.

De esa forma, solo recoreemos la cadena una sola vez y no dependemos de funciones externas para recorrerlo.

```js
let arrayTest = ['Arturo', 'Gabriela', 'Herminio', 'Leticia'];

maxcadena = "";

for (cadena of arrayTest) {
  if (cadena.length > maxcadena.length) {
    maxcadena = cadena
  }
}

console.log(maxcadena);
```

```js
let arrayTest = ['Arturo', 'Gabriela', 'Herminio', 'Leticia'];

    maxcadena = arrayTest[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < arrayTest.length-1; i++){
        if (arrayTest[i].length > maxcadena.length) {
            maxcadena = arrayTest[i]
        }
    }

    console.log(maxcadena);
```

Comment: Dejaré esto por aquí: https://jsben.ch/rEl7b (Ejecutar varias veces para ver lo interesante, a veces gana el código de gbianchi y a veces gana el código de Rddevelop)

Comment: En tema performance no debería haber una diferencia significativa entre las dos soluciones y por tanto no deberia ser un factor a tener en cuenta a la hora de elegir la mejor solución. Para mi en este caso es la simpleza del código lo que manda y lo que no entiendo es por que es mejor usar un foreach construido por uno mismo en lugar de usar la funcion sort que te ofrece el propio lenguaje ...

Comment: En el tema de performance, en teoría sí debería haber diferencia significativa dado que realizar un ordenamiento de un arreglo consume más recursos que solo recorrer un arreglo. Me ha llamado mucho la atención, en especial con el benchmark que hice en la página antes mostrada donde a veces gana una respuesta y a veces gana otra, sería cosa de probar con más registros y ver cómo se comporta. Cosas interesantes se aprenden cada día, en especial en comunidad :D

Comment: También tienes mi +1. Igualmente te invito a leer [¿Estamos utilizando demasiado poco el cierre por duplicado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4757/estamos-utilizando-demasiado-poco-el-cierre-por-duplicado-no-usamos-demasiado). La pregunta es duplicada.